# Windows and System memory

Tags: windows

What is the maximum amount of memory any single process on Windows can address? Is this different than the maximum virtual memory for the system? How would this affect a system design?

Comment: Virtual memory != page file. So "maximum virtual memory" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

On 32-bit versions of Windows, a single process can map and address no more than 3GB of virtual memory at time. In 64-bit versions of Windows, a 32-bit process can map and address no more than 4GB of virtual memory at a time.

For 64-bit processes, the amount is difficult to calculate as there are numerous overlapping limits that could apply depending on all kinds of factors. It's typically around 7TB.

The maximum amount of virtual memory for the system is difficult to calculate and not a very meaningful number. Also, the limits on physical memory are not related to these limits on virtual memory.

You can read more details on Microsoft's page, [Memory Limits for Windows Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).